# Tool to generate files based on user input

Tags: code-generation, auto-generate, generated-code

I am trying to find a tool that have some these inputs
1. User input(mostly numeric values) 
2. Template files that have keywords in a specific format

The tool should then be able to replace the keywords in template files with values based on user input

This could be a standalone tool, a script or a library to use in any language

Comment: Sorry but this isn't a programming question.  Maybe one of the other stack exchanges, like https://superuser.com/ could help?